# Secure Code Warrior Server-Side Request Forgery

Tags: url, ssrf

I am currently doing a problem on Secure Code Warrior's Java basic package, and the topic is server-side request forgery. The task is to try and access the "/vault" api through a parameter url. One of the files requires that the ip address starts with 127.0 or ::1, which I'm pretty sure means that we just have to access this /vault api from within the local system. However, I have been unsuccessful in trying to access /vault through changing the url parameter in the question.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just done it, and here is how. You should input everything beginning from `statements`

```
https://..../statements/13?url=http://127.0.0.1:5000/vault
```